# Octave permissions on Ubuntu 16.04 after installing from PPA

Tags: 16.04, permissions, ppa, octave

I've installed octave on xenial using PPA:

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install octave
```

after which I did not get root permissions, error being :

> The settings file /home/user/.config/octave/qt-settings does not exist and can not be created.
>   Make sure you have read and write permissions to /home/user/.config/octave
>   Octave GUI must be closed now.

It was a known issue as I came to know after a bit of browsing, fixed that by:

```
cd .config/octave
sudo chown user qt-settings
```

Now I still get issue with permissions, when I try saving a sample *.m file* and I had to :

`sudo chown -R user:user /home/user/.config/octave` to fix that.

I'm curious about why these issues arose?

- Something to do with PPA upgrading?
- Should I expect more issues or did I fix it enough?

I'd like to know more as I'm new to Linux & Octave on Linux.

Comment: do you run `octave` as a `root` or as normal user? what do you mean by *after which I did not get root permissions*?

Comment: I'm using as a normal user but the `.config/octave` was created in `root`.

Comment: Please excuse my terminology. I'm new to Linux.

Comment: What is the result of running `ls -lsa /usr/bin/octave`?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/user/bin/octave': No such file or directory

Comment: I suggested that you'll run the command ` ls -lsa /usr/bin/octave` in the command line, and post the result here. To make sure that the `octave` execution params are fine.

Comment: `16 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14760 Jun 21  2016 /usr/bin/octave`
Sorry I mistook `usr` for a replacement of  username

Comment: Okay, octave seems to be installed correctly. I'd assume that you solved your permission problem. I'd suggest that you'll try to use `octave` and see if the problem happened again. If so, update this question (or if it will be closed, open a new question with the full details)

Comment: Thanks for the verification. I didn't get any more issues yet. But I was wondering what was the cause. @Yaron any guesses?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue with the octave installation process , There are several questions about it here,  see also this [octave windows bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45634)

Comment: Yes, this was a known bug and should be fixed with the latest updates to the PPA.

Answer (score 0):

I tackle with the exactly same problem, and this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204226/octave-not-running-on-ubuntu-16-04-give-the-following-error-message) help me out. Here the code from the answer.

```
cd .config/octave

sudo chown $USER qt-settings
```